# How to enable jpeg support in node-canvas on x64 windows with MSVC10 compiler?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, node-canvas

I need to render jpeg images on nodejs serverside. I install canvas npm module
with following build instructions: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows
I have C:\libjpeg-turbo\ as it is mentioned in the manual. If I do:

> npm install canvas

then this piece of code doesn't launch onload:

```
 var data = fs.readFileSync("./t.jpg"); var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function () {
     console.log("onload"); 
 }; 
 img.src = data;
```

(it works with .png data). If i specify --with-jpeg in my command line, then MSVC complains about missing libjpeg.h. Right after this npm deletes file with msvc project, so I am unable to set paths myself (is it possible to switch off this cleanup?)

So how can I build canvas for windows with jpeg support? Found questions but no answers regarding this topic on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like binding.gyp is missing an 'include_dirs' directive at line #143 so the compiler can find libjpeg.h in the C:\libjpeg-turbo\  directory.  Try inserting:

```
      'include_dirs': [
        'c:/libjpeg-turbo',
      ],
```

Answer (score 3):

Install MSVC10 and 64bit nodejs.
When your build fails, use the following distributives, which you'll find on the net:

- unzip gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101229_win64.zip to c:/gtk . Use this
  version, others failed for me
- setup libjpeg-turbo-1.4.0-vc64.exe to C:\libjpeg-turbo (32bit libs
  would fail with no meaningfull message)
- go to the
  .\node_modules\canvas\build\ and modify your binding.gyp. Add
  'variables':

> ```
>   {
>     'GTK_Root%': 'C:/GTK', # Set the location of GTK all-in-one bundle
>     'with_jpeg%': 'true',
>     'libjpeg_root%':'C:/libjpeg-turbo',
>     'with_gif%': 'false',
>     'with_pango%': 'false',
>     'with_freetype%': 'false'
>   }
> ```

and also

```
['with_jpeg=="true"', {
          'defines': [
            'HAVE_JPEG'
          ],
          'conditions': [
            ['OS=="win"', {
              'libraries': [
                '-l<(libjpeg_root)/lib/jpeg-static.lib','-l<(libjpeg_root)/lib/jpeg.lib'
              ],
            'include_dirs': [
        '<(libjpeg_root)/include'
      ]
            }, {
              'libraries': [
                '-ljpeg'
              ]
            }]
          ]
        }]
```

then exec following commands in the folder, where .gyp file is located:

node-gyp configure

node-gyp build

IMHO libraries for such modules should be included as a part of npm distributions, its strange to expect WIN32/C++ expertise from nodejs programmer...